# Async BeginSend / EndSend does not send as much data as it says

Tags: .net, sockets

I have an embedded device that I am playing with; Sending some data from PC. With embedded device I am not talking about WindowsCE / Linux, but a microcontroller with crappy TCP-IP stack and a few KB of RAM.

The problem occurs when I try to send multiple packets and eventually flood the device driver.

What is the problem?

BeginSend and EndSend on PC both works without error and the total length of data pushed in BeginSend is the same as the returned EndSend length. But checking the number of data [bytes?] sent with Wireshark shows that there is not as many packets as there should be and this difference is a few KB. So, BeginSend and EndSend works as if they finished but they actually did not.

I have tried toggling Socket.NoDelay but it seems it does not work. Even if i set Socket.NoDelay = true, larger packets are sent, so it looks as if it has no effect.

I am of course using TCP sockets.

Sending that much data from a WebServer (IIS) works ok.

Are there any issues I should be aware of?

Comment: Why are you talking about an expected number of packets? The number of packets used can vary when you use TCP.

Answer (score 0):

> I  have embedded device and I am playing whit sending some data from PC. Whit embedded device I am not talking about WindowsCE / Linux, but microcontoller whit crappy TCP-IP stack and few KB of RAM.

Are you sending from a .Net application to this device?

> BeginSend and EndSend on PC both works without error and total length of data pushed in BeginSend is same as total of returned EndSend length. But checking number of data sent whit Wireshark shows that there is not as many packets as there should be and this difference if few KB.

How did you come to that conclusion?

> Sending that many data from WebServer (IIS) works ok.

Please elaborate what you mean? Do you send via HTTP to the embedded device and that works?

> Is there any issue I should be aware of?

What is the problem? Do the embedded device not receive everything? If so, how did you come to that conclusion?